# JavaScript - Combine both JSON request into one single Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, http

How can I combine two different JSON responses into one object so I can manipulate my data from a single source?

I've read different implementations, however not quite the way I have my code structured right now.

I'm pretty green on it, so if you can provide me a hands-on example that would be greatly appreciated.

ex:

```
$(function() {
    let hotels = 'data1.json';
    let guests = 'data2.json';
    $.getJSON(hotels)
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    $.getJSON(guests)
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

      /*** start logic for application here ***/  

    let newObject = //How can I combine both responses above???
    console.log(newObject);


});
```

Bellow the responses that I get from each request:
[image]

Comment: you want this in one *array* ?

Comment: what do you mean by "combine" in one object?

Comment: Have both responses saved into a new object. So can manipulate it having all data in one place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a `Promise.all` chain to get the both results in a new object.

```
Promise.all([$.getJSON(hotels), $.getJSON(guests)])
  .then( results => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Example: https://repl.it/Ls2c/1

Comment: Baruch,  this is already a huge step and thank you. Right now results logs  [Array(5), Array(6)], Could we concatenate the arrays? @Baruch

Comment: Please note that the Promise.all waits for the resolution of all the promises or the first that is rejected.

Comment: You can also destructure like this: `.then(([hotels, guests]) => console.log({hotels, guests}))`. To concatenate them, just use `results[0].concat(results[1])`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Xufox and Baruch !!

Comment: @Xufox if I were to use your destructuring suggestion, Would your .then example replace .then(results => { ..... ?

Comment: @tonkihonks13 He's not deconstructing, he's getting the values of each promise resolve from the arguments and setting them into a new object.

Comment: Ultimately, this console.log will return something like `{ hotels: [], guests: [] }`

Comment: @Baruch that makes sense. I just applied it and saw what you meant.